# Consulta errona con php y mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

No consigo entender el error, pero la cuestión es que tengo este código

```
$curp = $_REQUEST['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Persona,Perfil WHERE curp = '$curp'";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
```

Aquí genero una consulta simple a mi base de datos y me regresa los valores de la tabla `Persona` y `Perfil`, la parte que me interesa son los datos de la tabla Perfil, que no son más que dos columnas `salud_fisica` y `salud_mental` representados por datos de tipo `VARCHAR`, dentro de ese mismo documento tengo un formulario asociado a una funcion ajax para actualizar esos dos valores, que se pueden cambiar a traves de etiqutas `<select>` (tengo una función que carga los datos de la consulta en los select para que puedas ver que tenias antes) en el formulario, cuando cambio los valores y realizo la actualización la query se ejecuta correctamente y se ven los cambios reflejados en la base de datos, pero al recargar la página los valores que extrae la consulta inicial siempre son erroneos (distintos a los que hay en la base de datos). No entiendo que esta pasando :(

Aquí la función ajax

```
function updateProfile(){
    var curp = "<?php echo $curp; ?>";
    var phy = document.p_form.phyState.value;
    var mind = document.p_form.mindState.value;
    $.ajax({
      url: '../BackEnd/update_profile.php?curp='+curp+'&phy='+phy+'&mind='+mind,
      type: 'post',
      success: function(res){
        if(res == 0){
          alert('MISTAKE1: host not found');
        }else{
          show();
        }
      },error:function(){
          alert('MISTAKE: host not found');
        }
    });
  }
```

Aquí el formulario

```
<form name="p_form">
        <div class="form-group  col-md-5">
          <label for="phyState">Physical State</label>
          <select name="phyState" id="phyState" class="custom-select">
            <option value="null">select</option>
            <option value="Healthy">Healthy</option>
            <option value="Balanced">Balanced</option>
            <option value="Critical">Critical</option>
            <option value="Not Defined">Not Defined</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group  col-md-5">
          <label for="mindState">Mental State</label>
          <select name="mindState" id="mindState" class="custom-select">
            <option value="null">select</option>
            <option value="Healthy">Healthy</option>
            <option value="Balanced">Balanced</option>
            <option value="Critical">Critical</option>
            <option value="Not Defined">Not Defined</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick="updateProfile();">Update</button>
  </form>
```

Y por ultimo aquí el código para ponerles el valor adecuado a los `<select>`

```
<script>
  document.ready = document.getElementById("phyState").value = "<?php echo $row['salud_fisica'];?>";
  document.ready = document.getElementById("mindState").value = "<?php echo $row['salud_mental'];?>";
</script>
```

Comment: Qué error te pone?

Comment: ninguno, simplemente no carga los valores correctos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tenes que referenciar a cual atributo de la tabla seleccionas, puede que seas ambiguas ambas, ejemplo `SELECT * FROM Persona,Perfil WHERE Persona.curp = '$curp'"`  o  `SELECT * FROM Persona,Perfil WHERE Perfil.curp = '$curp'"`

Comment: La tabla Persona es la única que contiene el atributo curp, en todo caso lo acabo de probar e igual no funciona